# Оттоманские правители вместо османских — ничего?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика, прилагательные, синонимы

> Святой был настолько почитаем сербами, что вскоре и местное турецкое
>   население (после завоевания территорий в 1459 году) начало оправлять
>   его культ. Такая христианизация показалась оттоманским правителям
>   излишней. В 1594 году монастырь был разорён, гроб Саввы привезён в
>   Белград и мощи святого сожжены на холме Врачар.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас считается устаревшим, хотя у Ушакова дается как основной вариант. 
Так что - на волю автора. Я бы не стал править, особенно если имелась в виду стилизация.